# Position Div content so that it is not cut-off screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

All,

EDIT:
I need to know if anyone knows of an API which will allow me to:

Display a div content so that when the hidden div appears, its content is not cut-off, in other words, some of the div content is not off screen so to speak. This will save me writing java script code for each situation that I need this for.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you use jQuery? You would be better off keeping you styles in a stylesheet.

Comment: Initially, the content I want to show is hidden. The user clicks on an icon and then I show the content. It is basically a calendar w/ items for each day, when user clicks on days that are closer to the right edge of the screen, the content appears cut-off when it is shown.

Comment: Right. Make these divs in html with `class='hidden yourclass'`, then `$('.youricon').click(() => $('.yourclass').removeClass('hidden'))`

Comment: I was looking for something more in the direction of an always visible div, so that when you scroll the page, div scrolls w/ it. I think I am going to use the jQuery UI position function which seems very handy if I don't find a magic div.

Comment: Please read [ask], and show us your code.

Comment: I have corrected my question, and have found a possible solution: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a great solution I was looking for:
http://css-tricks.com/jquery-ui-position-function/
It positions the content and ensures that it is not cut-off from the view port.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if([DivObj].style.left + [DivObj].style.width > window.innerWidth) {
  [DivObj].style.left = (window.innerWidth - [DivObj].style.width);
}
```

You can also do the same with height.